# pyqt5 выполнить перед закрытием

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, closeevent

Мне нужно вызвать метод `save_changes()` перед закрытием программы.
Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста))))))

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставляйте ВСЕГДА  [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> void QWidget::**closeEvent**(QCloseEvent *event)
>
> Этот обработчик событий вызывается с заданным событием, когда Qt получает запрос на закрытие окна для виджета верхнего уровня от оконной системы.
>
> По умолчанию событие принимается, а виджет закрывается. Вы можете повторно реализовать эту функцию, чтобы изменить способ ответа виджета на запросы закрытия окна. Например, вы можете предотвратить закрытие окна, вызвав ignore () для всех событий.
>
> Приложения главного окна обычно используют повторные реализации этой функции, чтобы проверить, сохранена ли работа пользователя, и запросить разрешение перед закрытием. Например, в примере приложения используется вспомогательная функция, чтобы определить, закрывать ли окно или нет:

```
def save_changes():
    ...

...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        save_changes()

...
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое!